# Android Navigation Components always returns to the start destination

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation

I'm using the Navigation Component and I have 1 Activity with 3 fragments (startDestination: mainFragment , levelFragment and gameFragment). if I'm in levelFragment, it returns to mainFragment, and if I'm in gameFragment it should return to levelFragment, but it returns to mainFragment instead.

I followed the documentation in order to solve the problem but I didn't find any solutions and it's still happening, Why?

Note: gameFragment returns to levelFragment(it appears for just a split second) then immediately returns to mainFragment.

Here's my navigation.xml :

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main_nav"
app:startDestination="@id/mainFragment">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/mainFragment"
    android:name="com.hroub.physicsapp.MainFragment"
    android:label="fragment_main"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main" >
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_mainFragment_to_levelFragment"
        app:destination="@id/levelFragment"
        app:enterAnim="@android:anim/fade_in"
        app:exitAnim="@android:anim/fade_out"
        app:popEnterAnim="@android:anim/fade_in"
        app:popExitAnim="@android:anim/fade_out" />
</fragment>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/gameFragment"
    android:name="com.hroub.physicsapp.GameFragment"
    android:label="fragment_game"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_game" >
    <argument
        android:name="index"
        app:argType="integer"
        android:defaultValue="0" />
    <argument
        android:name="concept"
        app:argType="com.hroub.physicsapp.model.Concept" />
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_gameFragment_to_levelFragment"
        app:destination="@id/levelFragment"
        app:popUpTo="@id/levelFragment"
        app:popUpToInclusive="true"
        />
</fragment>
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/levelFragment"
    android:name="com.hroub.physicsapp.LevelFragment"
    android:label="fragment_level"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_level" >
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_levelFragment_to_gameFragment"
        app:destination="@id/gameFragment"
        app:enterAnim="@android:anim/fade_in"
        app:exitAnim="@android:anim/fade_out"
        app:popEnterAnim="@android:anim/fade_in"
        app:popExitAnim="@android:anim/fade_out" />
    <argument
        android:name="position"
        app:argType="integer"
        android:defaultValue="0" />
</fragment>
```

Code to navigate to levelFragment :

```
MainFragmentDirections.ActionMainFragmentToLevelFragment action = MainFragmentDirections.actionMainFragmentToLevelFragment();
action.setPosition(getLayoutPosition());
Navigation.findNavController((Activity)context, R.id.main_host).navigate(action);
```

Code to navigate to gameFragment :

```
LevelFragmentDirections.ActionLevelFragmentToGameFragment action = LevelFragmentDirections.actionLevelFragmentToGameFragment(concept);
   action.setIndex(getLayoutPosition());
   action.setConcept(concept);
   Navigation.findNavController((Activity)context, R.id.main_host).navigate(action);
```

from gameFragment to levelFragment :

```
Navigation.findNavController(requireActivity(), R.id.main_host).navigate(R.id.action_gameFragment_to_levelFragment);
```

Comment: Why do you have an `<activity>` destination if you only have one Activity? That type of destination is specifically for launching a new Activity.

Comment: sorry, that was the wrong one. I edited now

Comment: Without the Activity code, it's impossible to tell.

Comment: Mmm... There's actually nothing in the activity except this line in onCreate :   
Navigation.findNavController(activity, R.id.main_host).setGraph(R.navigation.main_nav);